# Issues on Microsoft.BotFramework + LUIS + .Net Core 2.0

Tags: botframework, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I had implemented a chatbot using Microsoft.BotFramework in a .Net Framework WebAPI and it's working, now I want do port it to .Net Core 2, to share some libraries, authentication ... with other projects.

The big issue is that everytime I try to run it, when the message is passed to my "Dialog" class, my bot crashes giving me the following error:

```
Exception: Type ‘System.RuntimeType’ in Assembly ‘System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e’ is not marked as serializable.
```

I tried to find some solutions but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using the libraries ported by CXuesong and following the sample found in https://github.com/CXuesong/BotBuilderPlayground.Standard

Now I have ChatBot with LUIS and QnAMaker running on .Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 2):

There is no  **official** `bot.builder` package compatible with AspNetCore. Therefor, you cannot use dialogs with AspNetCore.  There is however another user that has seemed to find a workaround in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3941).  There is also at least 1 unofficial package